# Search array of objects for a specific key provided from another array

Tags: javascript

I have an object with the structure of:

```
[
    {
        "id": "NONSTOPS",
        "label": "Nonstop",
        "value": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": "REWARDS",
        "label": "Rewards",
        "value": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": "SEAT",
        "label": "Seats",
        "value": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": "BAGS",
        "label": "Bags",
        "value": "no"
    }
]
```

and an array with a structure of

```
["NONSTOPS", "REWARDS"]
```

To return

```
[
    {
        "id": "NONSTOPS",
        "label": "Nonstop",
        "value": "yes"
    },

    {
        "id": "REWARDS",
        "label": "Rewards",
        "value": "yes"
    },

    {
        "id": "SEAT",
        "label": "Seats",
        "value": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": "BAGS",
        "label": "Bags",
        "value": "no"
    }
]
```

Based on the array, it would search the object and change the value to "yes" if there exists an ID on the array.

Here's my code so far

```
for(let i=0; i< obj.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j<array.length; j++){
    if(obj[i].id === array[j]){
      obj[i].value ='yes'
    }
  }
}
```

Something seems off about my code and I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, maybe with a mapper of some sorts?

Comment: `const ids = [ "NONSTOPS", "REWARDS" ]; const output = input.map(x => ids.includes(x.id) ? { ...x, value: "yes" } : x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can probably use a `.forEach` and an `indexOf` check on your array (just to be more concise, there's nothing wrong with your approach)

```
obj.forEach(o => {
    if (array.indexOf(o.id) > -1) o.value = "yes";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes`

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "NONSTOPS",
    "label": "Nonstop",
    "value": "no"
},

    {
        "id": "REWARDS",
        "label": "Rewards",
        "value": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": "SEAT",
        "label": "Seats",
        "value": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": "BAGS",
        "label": "Bags",
        "value": "no"
    }
]


const lookup = ["NONSTOPS", "REWARDS"];

const reduced = data.map(d => {
    return {id: d.id, label: d.label, value: lookup.includes(d.id) ? "YES" : "NO"}
});
console.log(reduced);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for of loop` to iterate over the array of objects and then check with the built in [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function if the value exist in the flat array.

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": "NONSTOPS",
        "label": "Nonstop",
        "value": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": "REWARDS",
        "label": "Rewards",
        "value": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": "SEAT",
        "label": "Seats",
        "value": "no"
    },

    {
        "id": "BAGS",
        "label": "Bags",
        "value": "no"
    }
]

const arrToCompare = ["NONSTOPS", "REWARDS"]

for (let obj of arr) {
  // you can use includes to find is the value exist in the arrToCompare
  if (arrToCompare.includes(obj.id)) {
    // if exists then mutate it
    obj.value = 'yes';
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4));
```

Answer (score -1):

In the question you have mentioned that you want to return the valid elements. You can use `filter()` for the same.

```
   var result = obj.filter(o => (array.indexOf(o.id) > -1) );
```